# sed _1 but not _10 _11 etc

Tags: sed

My data is structured like this in two columns:

```
ABC_1 ABC_1
XYZ_1 XYZ_1
ABC_10 ABC_10
XYZ_11 XYZ_11
```

I tried `sed /s/_1//g file_name` but it changed `_10` and `_11` as well.

How do I replace `_1` to nothing without changing `_10` or `_11`?

Comment: What Unix-like operating system are you using? I want to know it for compatibility issues might have.
And about your question, I'm not sure if you can solve it with `sed`. Do you have to use that command? I guess with `awk` might be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Change the regex!. Match what you need, add some anchor to limit the choices.

You do not say from where is the data being read. Is it a list of files? As positional parameters set by `set -- *`?. An array?, a File with each name on one line. An string ?

Assuming one file with two columns separated by spaces, and also assuming that you want to change every word that contains a `_1`if it is at the end of such word **or** at the end of the line. Then use `_1([ ]|$)`. Which means: match `_1` if followed by one space or at the end of the line.

```
$ cat infile

ABC_1 ABC_1
XYZ_1 XYZ_1
ABC_10 ABC_10
XYZ_11 XYZ_11


$ sed -E 's/_1([ ]|$)/\1/g' infile        # non-POSIX sed because of `-E`.
ABC ABC
XYZ XYZ
ABC_10 ABC_10
XYZ_11 XYZ_11
```

Comment: Or you can use word boundary `\b`

Comment: Thank you for your response. To clarify, it is in a tsv file. The columns are tab separated. I will try _1([ ]|$) and update. Why 's/_1([ ]|$)/\1/g' instead of 's/_1([ ]|$)//g' if I wanted to remove _1 (basically replace with nothing. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried your option? What happens? @ttn1883

Comment: No it didn't work at all. Not even _1 changed this time.